# merging arrays into one [["510", "511", "512", "513"], ["514", "515"]]

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

```
[["510", "511", "512", "513"], ["514", "515"]]
```

I need to merge this into one.

It should look like this:

```
["510", "511", "512", "513", "514", "515"]
```

Can anyone help me with this using javascript ?

Comment: And which language might this be?

Comment: Can you please show what you have already tried as well as what language you are working in? I'm sure if you do, someone will be able to answer your question.

Comment: My current logic is this:

$('li').each(function () {
                if (
$(this).find('a').hasClass('filterItemSelected')) {
                    arr.push($(this).find('a').attr('data-options').split(","));
                }
            });

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
      var array1 =  ["510", "511", "512", "513"] 
      var array2 =  ["514", "515"]

       var concatArray = array1.concat(array2);
```

Hope this helps